# Encog in Clojure, how to call compute()?

Tags: clojure, neural-network, encog

I'm trying to use Enclog, the Clojure wrapper for Encog, and I can run the example [on the main page](https://github.com/jimpil/enclog) just fine, but that only trains the net. I would like to predict values given new input. I'm aware the evaluation() function exists, but that outputs everything as a string, and I want a numerical vector instead. I've also tried

```
(def net
(network  (neural-pattern :feed-forward)
           :activation :sigmoid
           :input   2
           :output  1
           :hidden [2]))
(let [xor-input [[0.0 0.0] [1.0 0.0] [0.0 0.1] [1.0 1.0]]
  xor-ideal [[0.0] [1.0] [1.0] [0.0]]
  dataset   (data :basic-dataset xor-input xor-ideal)]
(.compute net dataset))
```

That is, creating a dataset and passing it in, but I  get a BasicMLDataSet to MLData casting error.

Is there a simple way to just run the neural net on new input vectors?

Answer (score 0):

`dataset` contains the training data, which includes the inputs and outputs.

You can run the computation with input only this way:

`(.compute net (training/data :basic [1.0 1.0]))`